# How to stop Ken crossing you up as Blanka?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

When you're playing Blanka, and Ken knocks you down, how do you stop him from chaining cross ups when you dont have any EX for a vertical EX ball?

When I've got no EX it just seems like he can keep jumping over me and throwing quick punches until I make a mistake or he catches me with a throw. What are my alternatives?

I should also mention that the ken player jumps in and uses light kick which beats electricity, and leads into a big damage combo for him.

Comment: Not a blanka player, but I believe electricity is a reversal so that might work in a cross up situation

Comment: I forgot to mention that he uses a jump in light kick, which beats electricity on the cross up. Will update the question.

Comment: ... block? Backdash can work as well, I believe.

Comment: Do you mean that he's just constantly doing crossup -> blocked -> crossup -> blocked -> crossup? I think you should just be able to jump out of that. Jump back fierce or something, even, possibly.

Comment: Hi Cloudy, yes that's what I meant. I'll try that today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is what cloudymusic pointed out, you just need to use an anti-air.

From the [Eventhubs](http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2008/jul/07/blanka-street-fighter-4-character-guide/) Blanka guide:

> Anti-Air Normals:
>
> [image: Hard Kick] or [image: Hard Punch] or [image: Down]+ [image: Medium Punch]
>
> > These are all of Blanka's anti-air normals. Hard Kick is for when the opponent is going to land slightly in front of you. Hard Punch is for when they are right above you. Crouching Medium Punch is when you have reacted a little too late to use standing Hard Punch.